# regex remove everything after character including that charecter

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to complete a regex which matches everything after a certain character including that character. eg if my string is

`"12:23:34:45:56"`

I want to return

`"12:23:34:45"`

Where everything after the last `:` has been removed including the `:`

I tried the below.

```js
var str1 = "12:23:34:45:56";
str1 = str1.replace(/[^:]*$/,"");
alert(str1);
```

Which returns `"12:23:34:45:"` (need to get rid of the last :)

I also tried

```js
var str2 = "12:23:34:45:56";
str2 = str2.replace(/:.*$/,"");
alert(str2);
```

which returns `"12"` matches to much of the string

How can I get what I want here?

Comment: Combine them: `/:[^:]*$/`

Comment: Any particular reason why you aren't using `lastIndexOf()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regexpless solution:

```
var r = '12:23:34:45:56'.split(':').slice(0,-1).join(':');
console.log(r); //=> "12:23:34:45"
```

Answer (score 2):

Another options are positive [lookahead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-lookahead):

```
var result = '12:23:34:45:56'.match(/(.+)(?=:).+/, '$1')[1];
```

or, as already noted by [Matt Way](https://stackoverflow.com/users/277697/matt-way), `lastIndexOf`:

```
var result = '12:23:34:45:56'.slice(0, '12:23:34:45:56'.lastIndexOf(':'));
```

**Update:** `lastIndexOf & slice` looks like the best solution in terms of [performance](http://tinyurl.com/nn7ud2v).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should consider this simple solution :

```js
var str='12:23:34:45:56';
var len = str.length;
while(len && str[len]!==':')len--;
var result = str.substr(0,len) 
console.log(result); // will output=> 12:23:34:45
```

Test :

```js
var i=0;
var tryIt=function(){
    var inputStr=document.getElementById('input').value;
    var len = inputStr.length;
    while(len && inputStr[len]!==':')len--;
    var str = inputStr.substr(0,len) 
    console.log(str); // will output=> 12:23:34:45
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 'result N°'+ (i++) + ' : <span>' + str + '</span>';
  }
document.getElementById('tryButton').onclick = tryIt;
```

```css
input {
  padding : 6px;
  margin  : 3px;
  font-size : 1em;
}
div {
  margin : 6px;
  }
span {
  border : solid 1px #999;
  border-radius : 9px ;
  padding : 6px;
  }
```

```html
<div><input type='text' id='input' value='12:23:34:45:56' ></div>
<div id='output'></div>
<hr><button id='tryButton'>try it</button>
```

Benchmarking :

```js
var inputStr = '12:23:34:45:56';
var len = inputStr.length ;
  
var suite = new Benchmark.Suite('foo', {
  'onStart': function(event) {
    console.log(this, event);
    out("Benchmark running... (please don't scroll)");
  },
  'onCycle': function(event) {
    console.log(this, event);
    out(String(event.target));
  },
  'onComplete': function(event) {
    console.log(this, event);
    out('Benchmark ended.');
    out('Fastest is "' + this.filter('fastest').pluck('name')+'"');
  }
});

suite.add("String split.slice.join", function() {
  var str = inputStr.split(':').slice(0, -1).join(':');
});
suite.add("Positive lookahead:", function() {
  var str = inputStr.match(/(.+)(?=:).+/, '$1')[1];
});
suite.add("Regex replace", function() {
  var str = inputStr.replace(/(.+):.+/, "$1");
});
suite.add("While loop", function() {
  len = inputStr.length;
  while(len && inputStr[len]!==':')len--;
  var str = inputStr.substring(0,len) 
});

suite.add("Slice lastIndeOf", function() {
  var str = inputStr.slice(0, inputStr.lastIndexOf(':'));
});
suite.add("While loop, with outside len", function() {
  while(len && inputStr[len]!==':')len--;
  var str = inputStr.substring(0,len) 
});


suite.run({
  'async': true
});

function out(str) {
  output.innerHTML += str + "\n";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/benchmark/1.0.0/benchmark.js"></script>
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

*Edit :*
Modified Benchmark test

the best choice is to use @CPH4 solution (noted by Matt Way) : `Slice.lastIndexOf`.

But if your texts input have all the same length so you have to consider the `negative while loop`.

Answer (score 0):

For me I don't know my answer matches with your need or not but I just want to help.

Instead of using replace() function you can use split() function to solve with that problem:

example :

```
var mystr = '12:23:34:45:56';
var myarr = mystr.split(":");
var myvar = myarr[0] + ":" + myarr[1] + ":" + myarr[2] + ":" + myarr[3];

alert(myvar);
```

or you can use this to remove : in the last

```
var mystr = '12:23:34:45:56';
var myarr = mystr.split(":");
myarr.pop();
var myvar = myarr.join(":");

alert(myvar);
```

Let's try it.

Comment: The first option is terrible. The second option is more reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulate the part you need in a capturing group, then you can use **$n** to get it.

Using a gredy match against `"12:23:34:45:56"`

```
/(.*)(:.*)/
```

Then used the first capture group `$1` is going to be `"12:23:34:45"` and $2 `":45"`

```js
var str = "12:23:34:45:56".replace(/(.+):.+/,"$1");
document.write(str);
```

### Benchmark

> String split.slice.join x 946,879 ops/sec ±0.53% (66 runs sampled)
>   Regex replace x 2,685,153 ops/sec ±0.87% (67 runs sampled)
>   Benchmark ended. Fastest is "Regex replace"

```js
var suite = new Benchmark.Suite('foo', {
  'onStart': function(event) {
    console.log(this, event);
    out("Benchmark running... (please don't scroll)");
  },
  'onCycle': function(event) {
    console.log(this, event);
    out(String(event.target));
  },
  'onComplete': function(event) {
    console.log(this, event);
    out('Benchmark ended.');
    out('Fastest is "' + this.filter('fastest').pluck('name')+'"');
  }
});

suite.add("String split.slice.join", function() {
  var str = '12:23:34:45:56'.split(':').slice(0, -1).join(':');
});

suite.add("Regex replace", function() {
  var str = "12:23:34:45:56".replace(/(.+):.+/, "$1");
});

suite.run({
  'async': true
});

function out(str) {
  output.innerHTML += str + "\n";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/benchmark/1.0.0/benchmark.js"></script>
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Comment: If the second group isn't being used or saved in any way, why use it at all? Why not just use `/(.*):.*/` instead?